# Image processing: filtering the background data - noise

Tags: image-processing, filter, scikit-image

I have data which contains 30000 images with 360x360 pixels. When I plot frames (e.g. frame 0), only a few circular cells can be seen in the plot(fig 1:frame 0 - active cell on the top left).

[image: fig 1:single image with the active cell on the top left]

However, when I plot mean of 300 or more frames, I see a honeycomb structure that is not seen in single frames (fig 2: max, median and mean images of 300 frames).

[image]

I need to calculate a mean or median image which only shows active cells on it, not this honeycomb structure. So, how can I filter this background from single frames?

So the method:
1.should filter this honeycomb structure from single images
2.shouldn't change the pixel values of the active cells (e.g. not like in binary threshold).
3.shouldn't be computationally expensive.

Do you have any ideas, recommendations?

Thank you,

Comment: Mh, you give us some pieces of information, but in fact you don't describe what you want to achieve. By the way, the number of images is irrelevant to memory consumption. Also what do you mean by "should not change actual values ​​except the filtered ones" ??

Comment: What is the connection between the plot and the max, median and mean images ? They don't seem to be rendered in the same scale.

Comment: I suspect there's a sequence of images involved...

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The noise is not the only issue. The image has very poor contrast, you should probably try [histogram equalization](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_equalize.html) first.

Then I would suggest applying a [median filter](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.median) to remove the noise.